# Main menu not redirect to url in mobile view

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, menu, mobile-menu

How can I change this in fresh Magento?

- 1. In mobile view, On click of the arrow, i want to open sub menu list.
- 2. In mobile view, On click of the main menu tab, I want to open main menu tab URL.

[image]

Comment: These two buttons (arrow and Demo) do what now when you click on it ?

Comment: Currently, it open sub menu lists only. and this is default Magento but I want to change this like when the user clicks on Demo Button It redirects to given URL and the arrow or any button open the sub menu. @Prince

Comment: So you have to find a DEMO button then you redirect it to your URL something like this: `<p><a href="your-url-here">DEMO</a></p> where is the problem ?
`

Comment: Demo URL is already set over there but when opening in desktop mode at that time I can click on demo menu and it redirect to URL but when I open it in mobile mode.it does not redirect to the URL. it is just open the sub menu list if you want to see this than you can install fresh Magento 1.9.3.3 and then create this type of menu and open it in mobile view.@Prince